# Open a link in a new tab, scrape, go to previous page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer for the following:

I switched `await link.click(".ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a",);` for `await new.page('...')` but it says that it can't find the `a`.

This is the page that I'm scraping but notice the Load More button at the bottom of the page.

https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder

To prevent resetting the Load more button I want to open each new in a new tab, scrape, close tab and go to the next name.

How can I open each link in a new tab, close, and go to the previous tab?

**My code:**

```
var buttonExists = true;
let allData = [];
while (buttonExists == true) {
// const loadMore = true;
const rowsCounts = await page.$$eval(
    '.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row',
    (rows) => rows.length
);
console.log(`row counts = ${rowsCounts}`);

for (let i = 2; i < rowsCounts + 1; i++) {
    const exerciseName = await page.$eval(
        `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a`,
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    console.log(`Exercise = ${exerciseName}`);

    await link.click(`.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a`,);
    await page.waitForSelector('#js-ex-content');

      ... fancy code here

    await page.goBack();

    let obj = {
        exercise: exerciseName,
    };

    allData.push(obj);

}
// clicking load more button and waiting 1sec
try {
    await page.click(LoadMoreButton);
}
catch (err) {
    buttonExists = false;
}
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector: `.ExCategory-results > .ExResult-row:nth-child(${i}) > .ExResult-cell > .ExHeading > a` is unnecessarily long and it gives you not completely correct results.

To get to these elements:

[image]

this selector should be enough: `.ExResult-row .ExHeading > a`.

Then you asked:

> I want to open each new in a new tab, scrape, close tab and go to the next name.

and

> How can I open each link in a new tab, close, and go to the previous tab?

In Puppeteer you can create a new page like so: `await browser.newPage();`, so you can do it many times and store the pages into an array:

```js
let pages = [];
pages.push(await browser.newPage());
```

then you get the links:

```js
const links = await pages[0].$$eval(
    '.ExResult-row .ExHeading > a',
    links => links.map(l => l.getAttribute('href'))
);
```

and finally to create a new page for each link, scrape what you need, and close the page:

```js
for (let link of links) {
    pages.push(await browser.newPage());
    await pages[pages.length - 1].goto(`${baseUrl}/${link}`);

    // your scraping

    await pages[pages.length - 1].close();
}
```

If you need to look up more, refer to the [API documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md) Puppeteer provides.